# Is the "boot menu" a new way to manage "boot order" in UEFI?

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios, uefi

I have HP computer where I enter UEFI/BIOS setup by pressing ESC key.

The options that appear contain "Boot menu" and also "BIOS setup". I can ofcourse go into BIOS seteup and change the boot order but I can just also just select "boot menu" where it presents all available boot optitons. I can than select the CD/DVD driver (or SAT0 or USB for that matter) to boot from.

My question is, is the "boot menu" the new (easy) way to boot from a device directly instead of changing the boot order?

The way I see it, in most cases, this almost eliminates the need to go into BIOS setup and change boot order (and then perhaps change it back again to restore old order) in order to boot from a device.

Answer (score 4):

The assumption in the question at the end of your post is right.

The bios setup is where you can define the default boot device order while the boot menu is where you can select a different boot device than default for that particular boot instead of changing the default and having to change it back later.

In summary, the boot menu allows for a one time exception to the default boot order in the UEFI/BIOS settings without need to change the default settings repeatedly.

More info on UEFI/BIOS from [HP's Support Site](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03801890).

Comment: Right on 'redundant', doesn't quite meant that going to change that wording..any suggestion? :)

Comment: I think your current title is adequate, although I would change "managed" (past tense) to just "manage" (present tense) for better grammar.

Answer (score 3):

> is the "boot menu" the new (easy) way to boot from a device directly instead of changing the boot order?

Yes, selecting a device to boot from is literally the purpose of a boot menu. Based on your question, you've already seen what it does.

But it's not new. It has been a widespread feature even on "legacy" PC BIOS firmwares as early as 2005, from what I remember. The introduction of UEFI merely made it mandatory.

Answer (score 2):

> …  in most cases, this almost eliminates the need to go into BIOS setup
>   and change boot order (and then perhaps change it back again to restore old order)
>   in order to boot from a device.

Yes, it eliminates the ***need*** to go into BIOS setup and change boot order. 
But, as common as the (change boot order / boot / change it back) scenario is,
it’s not the only paradigm. 
The boot order is the *default* boot order when you don’t go into the menu. 
Consider:

- If you’re in a laboratory setting,
  where you lots of experimenting with different distributions,
  or where you *frequently* use “live boot” tools,
  you might want to set your boot order to put your CD and your USB
  before your main, fixed storage device (HDD or SSD). 
  That way, if you want to boot from a CD,
  all you have to do is put it into the drive and reboot. 
  You won’t need to bother with the menu.
- If you’re a more mundane sort of user,
  you should probably put your main, fixed storage device at the top of the boot order. 
  That way, if you accidentally leave a CD in the machine when you shutdown / reboot,
  the system won’t waste time trying to boot from the CD.

  This, of course, is also important if people you don’t trust
  have access to your machine. 
  Of course it’s impossible to totally protect yourself against people with access,
  but, if you set your machine to boot from the fixed device by default,
  ***and put a password on your BIOS***,
  you can make it a little bit harder for them to get into your system with a live CD.